# Migrating from SVN to Git, buildnumber-maven-plugin configuration to generate build number in git repo

Tags: git, maven, svn

I have a big SVN repo. I used **git svn clone**, and cloned it to my local git repo. In SVN repo, when i use **mvn clean install**, i get a snapshot with a build number( I have the buildnumber-maven-plugin added in the pom). I am looking for the same to happen when i do **mvn clean install** in the git repo. what are the essential changes and configurations i have to make in the pom, for the build to work fine in the git repo?

I have git 2.9.1 installed and buildnumber-maven-plugin is 1.3.

Comment: Well. First you try it as you do in SVN and come here if at all you face issues.

Comment: I did try that. I am getting this error: 
 Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.3:create on project
Exception while executing SCM command. svn: E155007:  is not a working copy

Answer (score 1):

The buildnumber-maven-plugin checks the local repository first to see if local source code copy is modified or is not the latest as available in remote svn/git. If local copy is not same, the plugin will fail.

As you specified the error as *#### is not a working copy*, it means that when you migrated to git, you have not yet pushed your changes into remote git repo.
So, the solutions for this are -

1. Ask maven to ignore this step of comparing local copy with remote as following :

   mvn clean install -Dmaven.buildNumber.doCheck=false
2. Push your source code to remote repo first and then invoke mvn clean install.

Comment: I have tried mvn clean install -Dmaven.buildNumber.doCheck=false. That's showing the same error. If i remove the buildnumber-maven-plugin from the POM, the build is working fine. But no number is generated for the snapshot build.